# How do I insert a string into a JsonArray?

Tags: c#, windows-8

How do you insert a string into a jsonArray in C# using Windows.Data.Json? I would like to serialize it to save into my localsettings for Windows 8

I tried:

```
public static void saveString(String myString)
{

    if (!ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("listOfStrings"))
    {
        JsonArray jsonArray= new JsonArray();
        jsonArray.Add(myString); //error saying it is not a jsonvalue
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["listOfStrings"] = jsonArray.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wont a string as a value use :

```
JsonArray jsonArray= new JsonArray();
jsonArray.Add(JsonValue.CreateStringValue(myString));
```